# New Samsung Steam Dryer condensation in display

Tags: electrical, appliances, dryer, washing-machine

I just got my new Samsung electric washer with Steam Cycle, [This One](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Samsung-7-5-cu-ft-Stackable-Electric-Dryer-with-Steam-Cycle-White/50150414),
After using it I noticed it started to accumulate water vapor in the display in a way that makes it hard to read the numbers on it,

did any of you experience anything like that, is this normal? do you guys advise return and get another model or should I just replace it?[image]

Comment: Does the moisture vary over time? If so, what makes it worse and better?

Comment: @DanielGriscom I just had it today I used it only one time, I really don't think this should happen?

Comment: I have the same issue. Technician says the vent leading out of the house needs to be cleaned out, but it was recently cleaned. He replaced the control panel today and I am still getting condensation. I have noticed a lot of warm air coming out from behind the dryer from vents on the back right below the console panel.